# SELECT refering value to sub query

Tags: sql, subquery

I am trying to get a random id value from my table. The condition is that the selected value must not exist for the same id and different language (language is `lang` field)

**I do this:**

```
SELECT id_v as p,cont FROM value_phrase WHERE lang=1 AND
NULL IN (SELECT cont FROM value_phrase WHERE id_v=p AND lang=2)
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1
```

... but I do not get any results (It must be an error in my query, because there are many rows satisfying the *desired* condition.) How should I fix it?

-- SOLVED --

the solution is to use NOT EXISTS instead of NULL IN, and use table aliases to refer the first id_v into the sub query. This way (thanks to  Mark Byers):

```
SELECT first.id_v, first.cont
FROM value_phrase AS
FIRST WHERE lang =1
AND NOT
 EXISTS (
 SELECT cont
 FROM value_phrase
 WHERE id_v = first.id_v
 AND lang =2
 )
ORDER BY RAND( )
LIMIT 0 , 1
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Can you post some example data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if a value does not exist, use `NOT EXISTS`.

```
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ... )
```

Comment: Thank you, and... how can I refer my value so that `p` is the same `id_v` as the one I am looking for?

Comment: Use table aliases if you want to refer to both tables in the inner select.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition `NULL IN (...)` will **never** return anything, because a comparison with `NULL` always returns `NULL` and that is treated as "false" in a query condition.

Comment: I took this example from MySql docs, but misunderstood its function. Thanks all of you now for making me understand better!

Comment: @Kenedy: really? The MySQL documentation contains an example with an expression `NULL IN (...)`? Can you post a link?

Comment: I found this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/subquery-restrictions.html by searching this: "select where subquery result returns null"... and althoug I read an read it again, keep not understanding what NULL IN really does...